# Full width Divs

Tags: jquery, fullscreen, scrollto

Im working on a project that uses jQuery ScrollTo

I have 6 rows, each with 6 child divs , I would like each of these child divs to be 'full width' (edge to edge in the browser window).

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RZjrV/2/

here is a live version: http://www.david-haigh.com/Website-Files/index.html

Cheers! ;-)

Comment: Show code in question. I don't want to have to trawl through your website.

Comment: can't you just define width: 100% for the children in css?

Answer (score 0):

in css you can do something like

```
.child_div {
  width: 100%;
}
```

but it looks like it might need to be done with jquery/js like this:

```
$(".child_div").width($(document).width())
```

Answer (score 0):

Alot of times you would want fixed sidebars but full body...heres my fiddle for tht

http://fiddle.jshell.net/asadpakistani/8sSMD/

Demo:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/asadpakistani/8sSMD/show/